# Why print three times when using python multiprocessing on windows?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, window

Consider the following sample code:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool


def f(k):
    return k*k


ks = [1, 2, 3]
print("Hello")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(2)
    k2 = pool.map(f, ks)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(k2)
```

On windows, the output is:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
[1, 4, 9]
```

which is weird and ugly, not what I expected.

Same code on Linux, the output is:

```
Hello
[1, 4, 9]
```

which is what I expected.

Why three `print` on windows? I think in the same manner, the `ks` must also have been defined three times and maybe the import and function definition also been done three repetitive times. This is time and resource wasting, I don't know why the design on windows is like this.

OK, face to the facts, should I define all the variables and move all calculations outside `if __name__=="__main__"` to the inside to avoid the resource wasting? BTW, move the function definition inside will cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux supports fork, an operation that can split one process into two at any point in the code.

Windows does not support fork and creating a sub-process is more complicated. Data has to be serialized, the program has to be (re-) executed to some degree (the code on the module level).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows and other platforms that use `spawn` rather than `fork` to create new processes, execution of the new process begins from the *top* of the program and that is precisely why the code that creates the process must be within a `if __name__=="__main__":` block. If it weren't, then the new process would recursively create a new processes *ad infinitum*.

So, yes, you must move code that you do not want your new process to execute outside of the global space. Generally speaking, *defining* functions in the global space causes no real harm and it would be too awkward to move every function not used by a sub-process inside an `if` block.